# Laravel/Doctrine:How to make separate EntityManagers for each db connections?

Tags: laravel, doctrine-orm

I have two databases.How can I have different EntityManagers for each of them and once I called them I connect directly to the specified manager.
For example I have two managers named default and content and each time I need content I have to do this

```
$em->getManager('content')
```

But I want to have a ContentEntityManager class that when I call it directly connects me to this manager

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should probably resolve this using [bindings](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container#binding-basics) which you can specify in a service provider.

Comment: @PtrTon Yes thats right by contextual binding I can send the specified manager through controller but some of the controllers need both managers.Also contextual is kinda messy cuz I must register each controller in it.I think having two separate classes for each manager is a better idea but i dont know ho to do it

Comment: In that case what about injecting a factory instead? That factory can then provide either one of the entity managers depending on the situation.